# Azure push notification within iOS

Tags: ios, azure

I am trying to integrate Azure Push Notification into my project. I have created a dummy project and wanted to test it before I start messing with my project. After following all the steps (as per Azure's documentation) and getting to the step where you build and run the project before sent a test push. I get

"Endpoint is missing or not in URL format in connectionString" in the log screen.

Any advice

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined you HUBLISTENACCESS correctly? It should be in the format

```
Endpoint=sb://<your namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;/SharedAccessKey=<your shared access key>
```

and do you have the correct HUBNAME?

Comment: I fixed the issue, I accidentally forgot to remove the end ">" while copying the endpoint from Azure. Thanks for taking a shot at it.